# Is my understanding of a smooth k-dimensional surface accurate?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, surfaces

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich, In section 12.1, it gives the definition of a k-dimensional surface, and then giving some argument, he gives the definition of *smooth* k-dimensional surface, but I'm really confused by those arguments in between, so to make sure, is my understand of a smooth $k$-dimensional surface correct ?

**My understanding:**

> A smooth $k$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subset $S
>  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k $ each point of which has a neighbourhood in
>   $S$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$ and those homeomorphisms
>   are in the class of $\mathbb{C}^m$ ($m\geq 1$) and are bijections.

Of course, the smoothness of the surface is the same as the degree of the smoothness of $m$ those homeomorphisms.

**Further questions:**

Do we need that those homeomorphism to be diffeomorphims ? i.e. do their inverse also have to be in the class of $C^m$ ?

Comment: Not quite: it has a neighborhood (in $S$) that's homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^k$ (note the $k$ rather than $n$). So a 2-D surface in 3-space (like the sphere) has, for each point, a nhd homeomorphic to the plane (or, better, an open subset of the plane).

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for pointing out. Actually, that was just a typo.

Comment: @JohnHughes By the way, do you know whether I need $f^{-1} \in C^m$ too ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas How would you define a differentiable map $S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$? $S$ does not need to be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the usual definition of differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$ won't work.

Comment: @asdq I do not understand, how so ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas In order to define differentiability of a function with domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $x$, we need a small open ball around $x$ such that the function is defined for every $y$ in that ball. Take a look at how you defined differentiability.

Comment: @asdq Can't we use  $U_S (x) = S\cap U(x),\quad where \quad U(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k $. By the subspace topology of $S$,  $U_S (x)$ is open.

Comment: Yes it is open in $S$, but unless you have defined differentiability for domains other than open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, this won't help since $U_S(x)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general.

Comment: @asdq Yes, we have a definition for the differentiability on set which are not presumed to be open, so I see no problem in here.

Answer (score 2):

$S$ must be locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$, not to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $U\subset S$ is open with $\phi\colon U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ a homeomorphism. The smoothness you are referring to then actually means that $i\circ\phi^{-1}$ is $C^m$, where $i:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is the inclusion map.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please also see my edit.